# How to add points to a variable?

Tags: python

I want to use the user `input` value and add it to an existing `points` variable.

Here's the code I have:

```
points= 0
add = input()
if add == 1:
    points+= 20

print (points)
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Try `add = int(input())`

Comment: `input` returns a string, not an integer which you are testing for.

Comment: AWESOME! THANKYOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 1):

When you take input in python its in string format you have to convert it into an integer.

```
points= 0
add = int(input())
if add == 1:
     points+= 20

print (points)
```